# Having trouble with find in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, find

I'm relatively new to VBA and I'm trying to program a command button click to find a cell in column C that contains an exact string and copy it to my clipboard using .find() but keep getting the error "Object Variable or With block variable not set". My code is attached below, thank you in advance.

```
Private Sub CommandButton9_Click()
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("GENERATOR").Columns(3).Find(What:="PUNCH HOLE ANGLE", LookAt:=xlWhole).Select
    Selection.Copy
End Sub
```

Comment: That means that the `Find` was unsuccessful. Try specifying `LookIn` as well.

Comment: Don't try to do everything in one line. The error probably means the item is not found. IS YOUR SEARCH CASE SENSITIVE OR DO YOU JUST LIKE CAPS?

Comment: @SJR The string I am searching for is in CAPS, yes.

Comment: Then specify `MatchCase:=True` as well.

Comment: @BigBen LookIn worked, thank you so much

Comment: You will still get errors if the term is not found.

Comment: @BigBen: Sorry for bothering, but I do not understand how `LookIn` could make a difference (unless the string is in a comment)?

Comment: @VBasic2008 - `xlFormulas` vs `xlValues` too? `Find` definitely behaves differently based on formulas or values.

Comment: @BigBen: I know, but give me a scenario when searching for an exact string it should make a difference.

Comment: Apparently OP's setup :-) . Sorry, i don't have more. `LookIn` should definitely be specified though as mentioned by the docs.

Comment: @BigBen:  Sorry, I remembered. `xlValues` might fail when cells are hidden.